# hook_views_data and DECIMAL columns

Tags: views

I have an external database that I am wiring into views with [`hook_views_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).  This particular database is making use of [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) data type.  What are the proper field, filter, etc, handlers to use with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'numeric' type classes handle both integers and floats/decimals:

- Field handler: [`views_handler_field_numeric`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_field_numeric.inc/class/views_handler_field_numeric/7)
- Filter handler: [`views_handler_filter_numeric`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter_numeric.inc/class/views_handler_filter_numeric/7)
- Argument handler: [`views_handler_argument_numeric`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_argument_numeric.inc/class/views_handler_argument_numeric/7)
- Validation plugin: [`views_plugin_argument_validate_numeric`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_argument_validate_numeric.inc/class/views_plugin_argument_validate_numeric/7)

It's not that obvious at face value, but if you look at the comments for `views_handler_field_numeric`:

> Definition terms:
>
> - float: If true this field contains a decimal value. If unset this field will be assumed to be integer.

So setting `'float' => TRUE` on your field definition, and using the `numeric` handlers, is all you need to do. e.g

```
$data['some_table']['msrp'] = array(
  'title' => t('MSRP'),
  'help' => t('MSRP of the product.'),
  'field' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
    'click sortable' => TRUE,
    'float' => TRUE,
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `hook_view_data()` for all type of data type other than just numeric and related fields is explained in the code below.

```
function hook_views_data() {
  // This example describes how to write hook_views_data() for the following
  // table:
  //
  // CREATE TABLE example_table (
//   nid INT(11) NOT NULL         COMMENT 'Primary key; refers to {node}.nid.',
//   plain_text_field VARCHAR(32) COMMENT 'Just a plain text field.',
//   numeric_field INT(11)        COMMENT 'Just a numeric field.',
//   boolean_field INT(1)         COMMENT 'Just an on/off field.',
//   timestamp_field INT(8)       COMMENT 'Just a timestamp field.',
//   PRIMARY KEY(nid)
  // );

  // First, the entry $data['example_table']['table'] describes properties of
  // the actual table – not its content.

  // The 'group' index will be used as a prefix in the UI for any of this
  // table's fields, sort criteria, etc. so it's easy to tell where they came
  // from.
  $data['example_table']['table']['group'] = t('Example table');

  // Define this as a base table – a table that can be described in itself by
  // views (and not just being brought in as a relationship). In reality this
  // is not very useful for this table, as it isn't really a distinct object of
  // its own, but it makes a good example.
  $data['example_table']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'nid', // This is the identifier field for the view. 
    'title' => t('Example table'), 
    'help' => t('Example table contains example content and can be related to nodes.'), 
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  // This table references the {node} table. The declaration below creates an
  // 'implicit' relationship to the node table, so that when 'node' is the base
  // table, the fields are automatically available.
  $data['example_table']['table']['join'] = array(
    // Index this array by the table name to which this table refers.
    // 'left_field' is the primary key in the referenced table.
    // 'field' is the foreign key in this table.
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid', 
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );

  // Next, describe each of the individual fields in this table to Views. This
  // is done by describing $data['example_table']['FIELD_NAME']. This part of
  // the array may then have further entries:
//   - title: The label for the table field, as presented in Views.
//   - help: The description text for the table field.
//   - relationship: A description of any relationship handler for the table
//     field.
//   - field: A description of any field handler for the table field.
//   - sort: A description of any sort handler for the table field.
//   - filter: A description of any filter handler for the table field.
//   - argument: A description of any argument handler for the table field.
//   - area: A description of any handler for adding content to header,
//     footer or as no result behaviour.
  //
  // The handler descriptions are described with examples below.

  // Node ID table field.
  $data['example_table']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Example content'), 
    'help' => t('Some example content that references a node.'),
    // Define a relationship to the {node} table, so example_table views can
    // add a relationship to nodes. If you want to define a relationship the
    // other direction, use hook_views_data_alter(), or use the 'implicit' join
    // method described above. 
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node', // The name of the table to join with. 
      'base field' => 'nid', // The name of the field on the joined table.
      // 'field' => 'nid' -- see hook_views_data_alter(); not needed here. 
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship', 
      'label' => t('Default label for the relationship'), 
      'title' => t('Title shown when adding the relationship'), 
      'help' => t('More information on this relationship'),
    ),
  );

  // Example plain text field.
  $data['example_table']['plain_text_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Plain text field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a plain text field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE, // This is use by the table display plugin.
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ), 
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  **// Example numeric text field.**
  $data['example_table']['numeric_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Numeric field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a numeric field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  // Example boolean field.
  $data['example_table']['boolean_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Boolean field'), 
    'help' => t('Just an on/off field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_boolean', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_boolean_operator',
      // Note that you can override the field-wide label: 
      'label' => t('Published'),
      // This setting is used by the boolean filter handler, as possible option. 
      'type' => 'yes-no',
      // use boolean_field = 1 instead of boolean_field <> 0 in WHERE statment. 
      'use equal' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  // Example timestamp field.
  $data['example_table']['timestamp_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Timestamp field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a timestamp field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7.x-3.x